# why pd.Series(A,B) prints out the column in reversed order (B,A)?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to understand why `pd.Series(Names, Scores)` generates columns in reversed order (Scores, Names) instead of (Names,Scores).

```
import pandas as pd

names  = ['Paul', 'Tom', 'Jill']
scores = [100, 90, 80]

my_series = pd.Series(names, scores)
print(my_series)
```

And outcome is:

```
|100|    Paul|
|90 |     Tom|
|80 |    Jill|
dtype: object
```

Comment: The syntax is `pd.Series(data=None, index=None)`, that is the latter would be the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `Series`' class parameter documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html

You're passing `names` as your data and `scores` as your indices; that's why they seem to have "switched places" in your outcome.
Mind that `Series` will generate a **one-dimensional** array (i.e. it only has one column). You seem to be wanting to generate a Dataframe, for which you will need to use `pd.DataFrame` after zipping your two lists:

```
data = list(zip(names, scores))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['names','scores'])

>    names scores
> 0  Paul  100
> 1  Tom   90
> 2  Jill  80
```